# How to get the last value from url in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I need to get the last value from the given url in smarty

```
My url : http://localhost/htdocs/cscart_mutli_car/electronics/computers/desktops/

I need to get "desktops" from the above url
```

How can i do that . Please help me.

Comment: Is this your url calling for categories and then sub-categories ?

Comment: If you print_r($_REQUEST), what you get ?

Comment: No i need to display desktop on tpl file

Comment: Extract the fragment in `PHP` (get it from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), assign it to your `Smarty` object, use it in templates.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
{assign var="last_dir" value="/"|explode:$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
{assign var="last_key" value=$last_dir|count}
{assign var="last_dir" value=$last_dir[$last_key-2]}
{$last_dir}
```