# How to get the parameter in smarty tpl

Tags: php, smarty

How do I get parameter from URL smarty file in Code-igniter

This is my route

```
$route['category/(:num)']   = 'Home/category/$1';
```

From this how to get num from URL:

```
$route['category/(:num)']   = 'Home/category/$1';
```

example My url is

```
http://localhost/webly/category/4
```

in this how do get **number** or **4** from url in smarty tpl

I got the ans from other question

```
{assign var="last_dir" value="/"|explode:$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
            {assign var="last_key" value=$last_dir|count}
            {assign var="last_dir" value=$last_dir[$last_key-1]}
            {$last_dir}
```

[link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146678/how-to-get-the-last-value-from-url-in-smarty)

Comment: Can you clarify your question please ? Show us your smarty code and your php code please.

Comment: Hi im using smarty tpl file in codeIgnitor 

my url is like this

http://localhost/webly/category/4

how do i get that 4 in smarty tpl file

Comment: The better way is to pass this '4' with PHP to your tpl

Comment: no the number is dynamic will change after another category clicks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}
```

And make some operations to get the '4' with regex

```
{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|regex_replace:"/\/([^/]*)$/":""}
```

And you can assign the result to an other variable

Comment: With pleasure, don't forget to accept my response if it's ok